# Delphi ODBC Connection Dialog Component?

Tags: database, delphi, odbc, runtime

I am thinking about adding ODBC database connectivity to an application.

The user will at runtime configure and select their database odbc connection.

Are there any components that will give me the required series of dialogs ?

Allowing the user to select the data source type, select drivers, browse already
defined ODBC connections etc.

Cheers
Sam

Comment: I will try the suggested solutions and come back asap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this, if you are using ADO components.

**Option 1**

```
  Uses
    OleDB,
    ComObj,
    ActiveX;

    function Edit_ADO_ODBC_ConnectionString(ParentHandle: THandle; InitialString: WideString;out NewString: string): Boolean;
    var
      DataInit  : IDataInitialize;
      DBPrompt  : IDBPromptInitialize;
      DataSource: IUnknown;
      InitStr   : PWideChar;
    begin
      Result   := False;
      DataInit := CreateComObject(CLSID_DataLinks) as IDataInitialize;
      if InitialString <> '' then
      DataInit.GetDataSource(nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, PWideChar(InitialString),IUnknown, DataSource);
      DBPrompt := CreateComObject(CLSID_DataLinks) as IDBPromptInitialize;

      {
      DBPROMPTOPTIONS_WIZARDSHEET = $1;
      DBPROMPTOPTIONS_PROPERTYSHEET = $2;
      DBPROMPTOPTIONS_BROWSEONLY = $8;
      DBPROMPTOPTIONS_DISABLE_PROVIDER_SELECTION = $10;
      }
      if Succeeded(DBPrompt.PromptDataSource(nil, ParentHandle,DBPROMPTOPTIONS_PROPERTYSHEET, 0, nil, nil, IUnknown, DataSource)) then
      begin
        InitStr   := nil;
        DataInit.GetInitializationString(DataSource, True, InitStr);
        NewString := InitStr;
        Result    := True;
      end;
    end;



Result:=Edit_ADO_ODBC_ConnectionString(0,OldConnectionString,NewString);
```

**Option 2**

```
Uses
ADODB;

PromptDataSource(Self.Handle, InitialString);
```

**Option 3**

```
Uses
ADODB,
AdoConEd;

procedure TMainForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
ADOConnection1 : TADOConnection;
begin
   ADOConnection1:=TADOConnection.Create(Self);
   EditConnectionString(ADOConnection1);
end;
```

**You must Select "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers"**

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

PromptDataSource Function from the ADODB unit.  Two parameters are 
required:

1. the calling form's handle
2. a connection string .  If  you want no default connection string
   just pass an empty string as:

   `var sConn : WideString; 
   begin 
        sConn := PromptDataSource(Form1.Handle, ''); 
   end;`