# How to integrate a connection string builder into my app?

Tags: delphi, connection-string, delphi-xe2, ado

There is a screen available within ADO components, when you double-click on the `ConnectionString` property and press the `Build` button...

[image: Connection String Builder]

How can I integrate this screen (or one with the same capabilities) into my application to allow users to create a database connection string? I don't intend to modify the Connection String of any particular ADO Component in Delphi - but just be able to build a connection string so I can save it.

Comment: This dialog is related and compatible only with OLEDB and ADO Providers. I doubt which exists a general use dialog to build connection strings for any provider. maybe you can provide more info about what components and providers are you using.

Comment: @RRUZ Well, in the prior tab of this screen (Provider) is where you pick the exact provider. I know it's only compatible with ADO, that's why I tagged my question so :-)

Comment: But you are using ADO?

Comment: Yes, just the user won't be building this directly for any particular instances of any ADO components.

Comment: Ok, then use the option 2 of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476772/delphi-odbc-connection-dialog-component) like so `InitialString:=PromptDataSource(Handle, InitialString);`

Comment: Yup, already there :-) Thanks. Option 1 seems more interesting though

Comment: I don't expose this much Goo to my users. I allow them to enter a server name (machine\instance), database name, select SQL Auth versus Integrated, and in the case of SQL AUth, input a user name and password. I wrote my own dialog. Took 10 minutes. Works great. Also added discovery features, similar to the connection dialog in SSMS.

Comment: @WarrenP Indeed I've done a few myself, very easy. However this application in particular is a database connection monitor. It maintains live connections with data sources and monitors timing and drop-outs (disconnection).

Comment: Oh cool. I was going to build one of those too.  :-) Wanna open source it and I'll throw my Mojo into it as well?

Comment: @WarrenP I assume Google Code is the most ideal place? I still have a lot to do, I haven't gotten the actual database testing threads structured yet, just the GUI and configuration. The threads are the next step of mine.

Comment: I love BitBucket + Mercurial. But Google Code is fine.  SourceForge has gone to the dark side though.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog in your image is "Data Link Properties Dialog". I don't have a Delphi example, but here is a link for a VB example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286189